# Finding if some tag exists in HTML response and printing if/else accordingly

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to collect data from a website (using Python). In a `webpage`, there are multiple listings of software and in each listing. My data is within a tag `(h5)` and certain class `('price_software_details)`.

However, in some cases, tag along with the data is missing. I want to print 'NA' message if data and tag are missing else it should print the data.

I tried the code that I have mentioned below, though it's not working.
Help please!

---

```
interest = soup.find(id = 'allsoftware')
for link in interest.findAll('h5'):
    if link.find(class_ = 'price_software_details') == True:
        print(link.getText())
    else:
        print('NA')
```

---

Comment: "it's not working" is a too imprecise error description

Comment: Have you tried using try: except: for error handling?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried error handling (try, except)?

```
interest = soup.find(id='allsoftware')
for link in interest.findAll('h5'):
    try: 
        item = link.find({'class':'price_software_details'})
        print(item.get_text())
    except:
        print('NA')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know `soup.find()` never be `True`.It only will be result or `None`.

```
interest = soup.find(id = 'allsoftware')
for link in interest.findAll('h5'):
    if link.find(class_ = 'price_software_details'):
        print(link.getText())
    else:
        print('NA')
```